# Getting back a deleted question

Tags: support, deletion, undeletion

I asked a question and posted it. Immediately I saw a flaw and deleted it hastily. Now I want it back to correct it.

What to do?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you want it undeleted then ping me.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I already did :-)

Comment: [I believe only 10k+ users can see deleted answers/questions; with the two caveats that users can see their own deleted answers, and can see their own deleted questions before they refresh or close the browser tab it's on.]

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Now I know!

Comment: See also: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)

Answer (score 2):

The original post is below:

---

I am not in algebraic topology or geometry or anything like this, but accidentally I came about the following question:

Given a connected closed oriented [surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface#Closed_surfaces) $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, e.g. a ball, a torus, etc.

Consider the family of vertex-transitive graphs [embeddable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding) into $S$. Such an embedded vertex-transitive graph may be seen as a homogeneous covering or "coordinate system" - no distinguished origin, no distinguished directions.

For a given surface $S$ consider the sequence of degrees of embeddable vertex-transitive graphs $\Delta$.

**Examples**:

- For the torus the sequence is $\lbrace 3,4,6 \rbrace$ (I guess)
- For the ball, its just $\lbrace 3 \rbrace$

**Question**:

- Is this sequence characteristic for a surface (connected closed oriented, in $\mathbb{R}^3$)?
- (How) can it - eventually - be calculated from the usual (Euler) characteristic?
- Is one of max($\Delta$) or min($\Delta$) directly related to another characteristic of the surface $S$?