# Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?

Tags: support, deletion, search, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Previously I deleted some of my questions, I wonder if there is a way to see (only) my deleted questions?

Comment: If the post is gone from the _deleted recent posts_ then look into your inbox for the comments on that post.

Comment: Closely related question: [How to produce a list of my own deleted answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10041)

Comment: Shouldn't this be on meta.stackexchange.com as it's not specific to the Mathematics Stack Exchange?  This looks like the closest thing to an existing duplicate over there: [How do I view my old deleted questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217169/308327)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### List of your deleted questions/answers

Navigate to the [question tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions) of your profile and click *[deleted questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current)* at the bottom. For answers, go to [answer tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=answers) instead - you'll get [list of your deleted answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-answers/current) in the same way.

#### Searching among your deleted posts

If you have 10K reputation, [searching for `deleted:1`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted:1) will bring up all of your deleted posts. Add `is:q` if looking just for questions, or `is:a` for answers.

The operator `deleted:1` works differently for moderators - they can [search among all deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134046).

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT:** Since now (January 2022) any user can get a list of all their deleted questions (answers), this answer is no longer relevant if you want to find one of *your own* deleted posts. I will still leave it here - I guess such queries might sometimes be useful also if you search for deleted posts *by others*.

---

**Original post:**

This is probably much less useful, but perhaps it can be used occasionally.

In [Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) there is also PostsWithDeleted table where *some* information about deleted posts is preserved. To be more specific, the data left for deleted posts are the data marked by <sup>1</sup> in the relevant part of [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677). They are Id, PostTypeId (1=question,2=answer), ParentId (for answers), CreationDate, DeletionDate, Score, Tags, ClosedDate. Notice that no data about the poster are kept.

So if some of this information that is kept might help you locate the question, you could be able to find it this way. A hypothetical example: If you remember that you have posted the question at some point during last summer and if you remember that it had tag which is not used very often, this might reduce the number of questions to check.

In the queries below you can find list of urls of posts which fulfill given criteria. You can click on them one by one - if you are allowed to see them (i.e., if you are either 10k+ user or if it is your own post) you can see for yourself whether that is the question you are interested in. (You can find similar queries also in this answer: [Are there some tools to follow deletions on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28315#28316))

- [Deleted questions posted between two dates with a specific tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/968721/deleted-questions-posted-between-two-dates-with-a-specific-tag)
- [Deleted answer posted between two dates - in a specific tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/968724/deleted-answer-posted-between-two-dates-in-a-specific-tag)

I will add that 10k+ users might use similar approach to find some of the deleted posts - if they remember some of this information about the post they are looking for.