# Suggest adding complete list of recently deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

It seems to come up [once in a while](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13948/is-there-any-way-to-see-my-deleted-questions) that someone is asking about whether it is possible to see ones deleted posts. It is possible to see for example the *deleted recent questions*, but there is no option to see a complete list.

I therefore suggest that this is made possible.

Comment: Yes, it does seem strange that it's hard to see one's own deleted content.

Comment: Now this seems to be [possible for 10k+ users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users). There is also this feature request on meta.SO: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). It is tagged ([meta-tag:status-declined]).

Comment: There was a recent change in Stack Exchange software and this was implemented. More details can be found here: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)