# Looking for a removed question. Can I still find it?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, search

Recently, I noticed that a couple of questions I posted were removed.

This is unfortunate, because my questions become a reference for me when I go back into the texts, and reading them again helps me.

I don't understand why the questions were removed, for me they seem to be of good quality, but maybe it is not up to me to decide, but to the caretakers of the site.

Still, I would like to know if it is possible to have access to the questions, so that I can store them in a safe place for my personal usage.

the questions removed were

in 16 september 2017

-Trouble understanding the use of the Branching Exclusion process. Question from a the paper from De Masi, Ferrari and Lebowitz

-Integrating for small values of x. A possible typo in the notes from Hairer.

-How to compute Lϵ(Yϵτ(ϕ))? A question on the paper from De Masi , Ferrari and Lebowitz

9 Sep 2017

-Estimates on the magnetization fluctuation field. A question concerning the paper from De Masi , Ferrari and Lebowitz

Comment: The questions are [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2394438/11619)  and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2394576/11619). Both were deleted by Roomba - a script deleting posts that meet certain criteria (low vote count, no upvoted answers,...)

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393056/integrating-for-small-values-of-x-a-possible-typo-in-the-notes-from-hairer and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382137/estimates-on-the-magnetization-fluctuation-field-a-question-concerning-the-pape

Comment: If the questions were not too old, you should be able to find them by yourself. Just click on "deleted recent questions" in [your questions tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions). For more details, see: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)

Comment: You usually can see it from the [reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) if you check the "show removed posts" at the end.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  I went to my reputation tab, being under 10K reputation when I check the "show removed posts" at the end, It doesn't allow me to see the deleted questions, only its title.
 I had another deleted question, how can I find it? its name is   "When a markov chain is not described by its truncated generator?"

Comment: No idea, sorry. Finding deleted questions is not something I'm very good at.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I had another deleted question, how can I find it as well? its name is "When a markov chain is not described by its truncated generator?"

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965385/when-a-markov-chain-is-not-described-by-its-truncated-generator