# Where can I see my deleted questions

Tags: support, deleted-questions, search

Sometimes I ask Questions which are regarded useless or off-topic and then they got deleted, however I have usually added many Details in the Body of the Question which help me to understand something when I am revising my notes. Where can I see those Questions?

Comment: Grammar error: I delete them because I think they are useless for a larger audience

Comment: See: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948) Since from your comment it seems that you are specifically interested in self-deletions, you could simply look at [delete votes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=deletion) in your profile.

Comment: Every post has a URL.  I keep a text file of questions and answers I may wish to see later, gathered together into sections by topic. This has turned out to be very handy, there is no possible feature of this, or any other, website that will organize hundreds of posts in a way that I find so useful.  Anyway, an ordinary text file, I call it Topics.txt

Comment: I apologize for the misinformation - I checked now on another site where I have lower reputation and it seems that on this site I can see my self-deleted posts in the tab with delete votes just because I have [10k+ reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). So the method which remains for users with lower reputation is to look at "deleted recent questions" - if the post wasn't older than 60 days.