# I want to view recently closed (not so recently asked) questions of mine

Tags: feature-request, search, closed-questions

Five months ago I asked

[Conjecture: Any odd integer $k>1$ has a partition $m+n,\,m,n>0,$ such that $m^2+n$ > is a prime.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3540015/conjecture-any-odd-integer-k1-has-a-partition-mn-m-n0-such-that-m2)

and a few days ago it was closed, which I noticed only because there also was a down vote.

Is there a way for me to view all closed questions of mine? So I can respond to it?

Comment: As you have above 10k reputation points, you can also search for your deleted posts: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948) (I know that question is about closed question - but perhaps knowing this might be useful, too.)

Comment: And I will also add that this feature request is marked as ([meta-tag:status-planned]): [Send authors an inbox message if their question is closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842). If it gets implemented, it will be easier to notice closures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can search for [`user:me closed:1`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+closed%3A1); the Stack Exchange search engine will automatically convert the `me` into your user ID.

There's no way on the main site to sort them and have the most recently closed ones shown first. For that, you'd need the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1263431/recently-closed-questions-for-a-single-user) does that; you do need to enter your own user ID (171248), and it will show you the results:

[image]

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`user:171248 closed:1`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A171248+closed%3A1). The number `171248` is your user number which can be found in the URL of your profile.