# Is it possible to view my own answer for a deleted question?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-questions

I was trying to remember a problem I answered a month ago but could not find it in my profile page answer list. I think it is safe to assume the question was deleted.

Is there any way I can look at a list of my own answers directly regardless of whether the question itself is deleted (in the hope of recalling the question)?

Comment: You have 10k, so the search "user:me deleted:1" should work (unless that's been changed in the last years).

Comment: See also: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Since you have 10k, it's rather easy: [search for `user:me is:answer deleted:1`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aanswer+deleted%3A1).

The link 'Deleted answers' at the bottom of [the list of answers in your profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=answers) works too, even for users who don't have 10k.