# A question missed in my "recently deleted answers" link

Tags: discussion, bug, deleted-questions

I had a deleted question (with no answer) two months ago and it could be found always in my recently deleted questions link. Today, I needed a good comment on that post but the post (the question) is missing from "recently deleted questions". Where has it gone? Is it erased forever?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32447/629362), recent means last 60 days.

Comment: @ArcticChar,  Is it erased forever? I mean no one can see it?

Comment: You can see the question *if you have a link*. And with a link, any user [with 10k+ reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can see the question. (And moderators can search also among deleted posts.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, Unfortunately, I don't have a link. It means there is no way I can see my own question?

Comment: Probably that's the post in question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4073939/applying-convexity-theorem-convex-analysis-for-discontinuous-functions

Comment: @quid, Thank you very much. I saved the link. Now, I can find it easily. Thanks again.

Comment: @LoopCorrections You could try Google Cache or Wayback Machined. If you remember *something* about the question, you could search a bit using SEDE. And, users with 10k+ reputation can search among their own deleted posts. But there is no *easy* way to find deleted question of another user or for users below 10k. You can find some SEDE queries to see what I mean here: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948) and [Are there some tools to follow deletions on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28315)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, You are right! I remember them. Thanks for your information.

Comment: Now that quid linked the question, I can include one example: If you remember that (convex-analysis) was used on the question, you could get the links to all of questions in this tag [deleted this year](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/845253/deleted-questions-between-two-dates-in-a-specific-tag?TagName=convex-analysis&Date1=2021-01-01&Date2=2022-01-01). As you see, you get 270 results - unless you remember also something else about that question, then the only things that remains is to go through the links one-by-one.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, I tried that; it worked. Interesting! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, perhaps that link could be added to the accepted answer Answer.

Comment: @RayButterworth - My problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: just go to your username and in the top put is:deleted

Comment: @Yorch As explained [in the linked post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13948/is-there-any-way-to-see-my-deleted-questions-or-answers), this works only for [users with at least 10k reputation points](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: Oh, my bad ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page gives *links* to certain deleted questions, namely those that are "recent." At some point the "recent" does not longer apply and thus the link is dropped from that list.

The question persists on the site just as before, the sole problem is to find it. The main way to do this is by preserving a direct link, via bookmarking the question.

Thus, during the period of time it was on the list you should have bookmarked it. Chances are you could still find it in your browser history, but to make things simple I'll try to give you a direct link in a comment.