# Recover closed question on math.stackexchange?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, closed-questions

Is there a way to recover a question (talking about Veblen ordinal hierarchies and tetration) on math.stackexchange that has been closed time ago? Need to archive its contents on my webpage and I remember seeing it as closed and non-visible to others, but I don't know if it was deleted permanently or not. I searched on m.se with user:myid;closed:1, and user:myid;"veblen"/"ordinal" but nothing is returned.

Comment: Do you mean https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859561/varepsilon-omega-reachable-using-a-corless-veblen-varphi-1?

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: yes, that's it. Many thanks! Should I presume that you have access to it because of moderation tools? Anyway, many thanks again!